# Javascript: Triggering "for" loop using "if...else" statements not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, checkbox, disabled-input

I am trying to make a simple script which automatically blocks the input boxes in the file when I tick a checkbox.
For this, I am trying to add/remove the "disabled" attribute by triggering a loop every time the checkbox is clicked. Looks something like this:

```js
function locker() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
  var x = getElementById("lock")
  for (i = 0; i < inputBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (x.checked == true) {
      boxes[i].disabled = true;
    } else {
      boxes[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="lock" onClick="locker()">
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work. I don't have much experience coding, and I feel like I am making a very basic mistake, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem so far... How can I solve this? Are there any other workarounds to get the same result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should defenetly learn JS basics and event handling first before trying to code something. At the moment your script is run the checkboxes dont exist.

Comment: `<input type="text"></input>` is invalid HTML. `input` cannot have a closing tag. It has to be either `<input type="text">` or (if you want to conform to well-formed-ness) `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: @CodeSpirit The HTML definitely exists before an online handler is executed.

Comment: It's `document.getElementById` not just `getElementById`.

Comment: `if (x.checked == true) {
      boxes[i].disabled = true;
    } else {
      boxes[i].disabled = false;
    }` can be simplified to `boxes[i].disabled = x.checked;`.

Comment: @Teemu You're correct, uppercase letters are valid, but are lowercased by the parser anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementById("lock")` instead of `getElementById("lock")` and use the correct variable names for your variables. You used `inputBoxes` and `boxes` while you meant to use the same variable.

```js
function locker() {
  var inputBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
  var x = document.getElementById("lock")
  for (i = 0; i < inputBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (x.checked == true) {
      inputBoxes[i].disabled = true;
    } else {
      inputBoxes[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="lock" onClick="locker()">
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Sorry, turns out I got sloppy with the coding, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Akiro Glad I could help, note that a checkbox can also change with the keyboard. So I think the `onchange` or `oninput` events are more suited for you. Blind people for example will not use a mouse but toggle it with their keyboard so for them they never fire an `onclick`.